# Problem when i request my API for store data in map flutter

Tags: android, mobile, flutter, flutter-layout

When i clicked in my `SwitchButton`, i save the id in `SharedPreferences`.
I recupered this id and i requested my API.

Because with this ID, i recupered all technologies.

But the problem, my list is reset at each id.

EDIT :

```
Theme theme;
List<Technology> technos = [];

class Technology {
  int id;
  String name;

  Technology({this.id, this.name});

  factory Technology.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Technology(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }

  Future<List<Technology>> getTechnologies() async {
    String id = await Theme().getTheme();
    String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/v1/api/theme/${id}/technology';
    String token = await Candidate().getToken();

    final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}',
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List technosList = jsonDecode(response.body);
      for (var technoMap in technosList) {
        technos.add(Technology.fromJson(technoMap));
      }
      return technos;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load technos');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it mean `technos` list always have only one entry? Can you print size of `technoList` to be sure it is being reset?

Comment: i printed my id string and technolist : 

1
I/flutter ( 7137): 2
I/flutter ( 7137): id : 2
I/flutter ( 7137): [{id: 1, name: GitHub}, {id: 2, name: BitBucket}, {id: 3, name: Travis}, {id: 4, name: Docker}]
I/flutter ( 7137): Dans le var : [{id: 1, name: GitHub}, {id: 2, name: BitBucket}, {id: 3, name: Travis}, {id: 4, name: Docker}]

We can see, technolist dont have the data for the id 2 @ChennaReddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my method :

```
Future<List<String>> getListTheme() async {
    List<String> themes = List<String>();
    final SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    for (String key in preferences.getKeys()) {
      if (key == 'token') {
        preferences.containsKey(key);
      } else {
        themes.add(jsonEncode(preferences.getStringList(key)));
      }
    }
    return themes;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because at each API you are overwriting `technos`  hence previous data is lost.
You can make this `technos` global on that `Screen` or if you use `BLOC` methods.

Use  `List<Technology> technos = [];` globally not in `getTechnologies()`.

rest is ok to add

```
technos.add(Technology.fromJson(technoMap));
```

Comment: yes I know, i tested this, but it's not worked... i don't have the techno of id 1 or id 2, it's depends when i clicked on the first

Comment: I edited my post, in my result, I have always in my list the data of id 2

Comment: Its still wrong ,it should not be global here, but in UI page you should have List that adds new result   `list.add(getTechnologies() ); setstate();`